# i have installed ubuntu 12.04 form usb and fix bootloder with boot repair now how to view that drive on windows?

Tags: 12.04

**View ext live journal filesystem in windows**
i have installed ubuntu 12.04 in d: drive and that drive get hidden when ubuntu is installed because it convert drive to ext4 live journal filesystem
How to view ext4 live journal filesystem in windows xp how to view that drive on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) "is an explorer like utility to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It now supports LVM2 and EXT4 extents. It can be used to view and copy files and folders. It can recursively copy entire folders. It can also be used to view and copy disk and file."